# What is the best place to read "Apotheosis" with all the chapters in the right order?

Tags: resources

I have been re-reading the manga/manhua/manhwa called "Apotheosis", and I have a hard time finding a complete version with all the chapters in the right order. Is there a good place for this?

Comment: Hi! Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Comment: That's fair. Official sites are good if they exist too.